# HTML / CSS (Speed Dials)

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner in HTML / CSS and just having practice in some things. I'm making Speed Dials like Google Chrome Speed Dials 2. I just have some questions and need your help.

Here is Code of it. All i want now is this dial, outlined here in this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPFPT.png) to be on the left side, not to be centered.

```
ul.main{            
        text-align: center;     
}
```

this is what makes it centered, but if i remove it, then the whole `ul` tag goes left...
I want final result to be like that [Video Example](http://1drv.ms/1nzaBw6)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Speed Dials Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: black;
            background-image: url(322423.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position-y: 15%;
        }


        ul.main{
            list-style-type: none;
            display: table;
            padding:0;          
            clear: both; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        li.dial{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            display: inline-table;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 10px;
            outline:0;
            margin:0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }

        li.dial a:hover{
            opacity: 0.75;
        }

        li.dial a{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #BADAFF;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
            padding: 10px;
            display: table-cell;
            text-decoration: none;
            color:#0000FF;
        }

        li.dial a:active{
            color:#0000FF;
        }

        .dial .site{
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        li.dial div.thumb{
            background-color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            display: block;
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
        }

        li.dial div.site{
            background-color: transparent;
            width: 100%;
            height: 14%;
            display: block;
            padding-top: 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }



        @media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 1245px){
            ul.main{
                width: 1099px;
            }

            li.dial{
                width: 260px;
                height: 175px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 1110px){
            ul.main{
                width: 978px;
            }

            li.dial{
                width: 230px;
                height: 152px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 986px){
            ul.main{
                width: 843px;
            }

            li.dial{
                width: 200px;
                height: 132px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 855px){
            ul.main{
                width: 750px;
            }

            li.dial{
                width: 160px;
                height: 110px;
            }

            @media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 760px){
            ul.main{
                width: 97%;
            }

            li.dial{
                width: 160px;
                height: 110px;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul class="main">
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_self">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/yIeoHS5.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">Facebook</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="http://google.com" target="_self">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5221/5612548667_a9b09a2068_o.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">Google</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">Gmail.com</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">Yahoo</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">TheNewBoston</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">PHPacademy</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">Geo.saitebi.ge</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">W3Schools</div>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="dial">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2561/1st_mx_is_4c/256/speed_dial2.png)"></div>
                <div class="site">Seo.ge</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by making a different .css fyle for your styles. It much easier to look at, and it's bad practice to place styles in the html/php page

Comment: And the image does not load

Comment: Your picture requires a login. Logins are scary. Please use http://imgur.com.

Comment: 1. Yes, i always use different .css file. i just do it now to insert HTML and CSS together here
2. Picture uploaded to imgur, sorry for it, i used onedrive.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty div with the class clean with value clear: both; This property prohibit wrapping. both Cancels wrapping elements simultaneously from the right and left edges. This value is recommended when you need to remove the wrapping element, but it is unknown exactly which side. or still refuse `text-align: center;`

Comment: that doesn't work. when i remove `text-align: center;` it just bring the whole `<ul>` tag on the left and while re-sizing browser window before it apply from one media query, to another `<ul>` tag goes left and on the right side of it there is space and that space is just re-sizing with browser window. all i want is, that content to be centered and while re-sizing it has same wide spaces on the left and on the right

Comment: then I recommend you to get acquainted with the framework bootstrap site of the current framework everything is easy to handle in the perception